# Deployd randomly fails to start mongod

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployd

I am having some weird occurances with my deployd instance.
Ususally I am starting localhost with "dpd -d" command. It happened to me twice now, that at some point mongod refuses to start and returns the following error:

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vRZI.jpg)

I can also not invoke "dpd --mongod" command as this is recognized as unknown.

I have not changed a thing and it was working perfectly before. The first time this occured I restarted the computer, deleted the mongo related files such as

[mongod file in .pids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycby3.jpg)

and

mongod.lock in data. (cannot post link, as my reputation is not high enough yet).

Both are created when starting up mongod.

I have no further idea how to generate an error log or fix this issue. I also looked up the other threads containing mongod failures, but none of the fixes seem to work/apply to my problem.

Any help is really appreciated! If I am not able to make this work again, does anyone has an idea how I can transfer my "-deployd.3", "-deployd.4" etc. data files into a different database so at least I won't loose the data I already acquired?

Thank you very much for your support!

Best,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Running deployd via `dpd` for anything but development is not recommended.

I suggest you run your own `mongodb` server instance, preferrably as a deamon, and use a `server.js` start script to initialize deployd.

You should be able to transfer the data folder somewhere else and run
`mongod --dbpath <data folder location>`

[You can find an example of such a deployd bootstrap script here](https://gist.github.com/andreialecu/a563c9a5ab7fdd7dc02f)